# Slightly different number of total frames between my program (using libav) and ffprobe

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, libav

For learning purposes, I made a routine that decodes each frame for each stream inside a given container.

I noticed that *for some videos*, the amount of frames returned by my code differs the one calculated by the tool ffprobe (which comes with ffmpeg).

I'm using ffprobe like this:

```
ffprobe <media file> -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_frames -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames
```

Replacing "v:0" with "a:0" for audio, etc.

And this is my source code:

```
void showFrames(char *szFilename) {
    int               iError;
    char              szError[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    AVFormatContext   *fcFormatCtx;
    AVCodec           *cdCodec;
    AVCodecParameters *cdpCodecParams;
    AVCodecContext    *ccCodecCtx;
    AVPacket          *pkPacket;
    AVFrame           *frFrame;
    fcFormatCtx=avformat_alloc_context();
    iError=avformat_open_input(&fcFormatCtx,szFilename,NULL,NULL);
    if(0>iError) {
        av_strerror(iError,szError,sizeof(szError));
        fprintf(stderr,"avformat_open_input() failed: %s\n",szError);
        return;
    }
    iError=avformat_find_stream_info(fcFormatCtx,NULL);
    if(0>iError) {
        av_strerror(iError,szError,sizeof(szError));
        fprintf(stderr,"avformat_find_stream_info() failed: %s\n",szError);
        avformat_close_input(&fcFormatCtx);
        return;
    }
    for(uint uiSt=0;uiSt<fcFormatCtx->nb_streams;uiSt++) {
        cdpCodecParams=fcFormatCtx->streams[uiSt]->codecpar;
        cdCodec=avcodec_find_decoder(cdpCodecParams->codec_id);
        if(NULL==cdCodec) {
            fprintf(stderr,"no codec found for stream %u\n",uiSt);
            continue;
        }
        fprintf(stderr,"stream %u\n",uiSt);
        if(AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO==cdpCodecParams->codec_type)
            fprintf(stderr,"video codec id=%d name='%s'\n",
                    cdCodec->id,cdCodec->long_name);
        else if(AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO==cdpCodecParams->codec_type)
            fprintf(stderr,"audio codec id=%d name='%s'\n",
                    cdCodec->id,cdCodec->long_name);
        else {
            fprintf(stderr,"unsupported codec id=%d name='%s'\n",
                    cdCodec->id,cdCodec->long_name);
            continue;
        }
        ccCodecCtx=avcodec_alloc_context3(cdCodec);
        avcodec_parameters_to_context(ccCodecCtx,cdpCodecParams);
        iError=avcodec_open2(ccCodecCtx,cdCodec,NULL);
        if(0>iError) {
            av_strerror(iError,szError,sizeof(szError));
            fprintf(stderr,"avcodec_open2() failed: %s\n",szError);
            avcodec_free_context(&ccCodecCtx);
            continue;
        }
        pkPacket=av_packet_alloc();
        frFrame=av_frame_alloc();
        av_seek_frame(fcFormatCtx,uiSt,0,AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME);
        while(0==av_read_frame(fcFormatCtx,pkPacket)) {
            if(uiSt==pkPacket->stream_index) {
                iError=avcodec_send_packet(ccCodecCtx,pkPacket);
                if(0>iError) {
                    av_strerror(iError,szError,sizeof(szError));
                    fprintf(stderr,"avcodec_send_packet() failed: %s\n",szError);
                    break;
                }
                while(true) {
                    iError=avcodec_receive_frame(ccCodecCtx,frFrame);
                    if(0>iError)
                        break;
                    fprintf(stderr,"stream %u, frame %d\n",
                            uiSt,ccCodecCtx->frame_number);
                    av_frame_unref(frFrame);
                }
                if(AVERROR(EAGAIN)!=iError&&AVERROR_EOF!=iError) {
                    av_strerror(iError,szError,sizeof(szError));
                    fprintf(stderr,"avcodec_receive_frame() failed: %s\n",szError);
                    break;
                }
            }
            av_packet_unref(pkPacket);
        }
        av_packet_free(&pkPacket);
        av_frame_free(&frFrame);
        avcodec_free_context(&ccCodecCtx);
    }
    avformat_close_input(&fcFormatCtx);
}
```

It's pretty much self contained but you may ignore all the initializations and go directly to the *while* after the call to *av_seek_frame()*. This is where the actual frames are being read.

BTW, I'm using av_seek_frame() because this program goes *stream by stream*, separating the frames, so I need to rewind with every stream found.

Anyway, I've tested the previous code with the following files:

#1. sample-10s.mp4 from https://samplelib.com/sample-mp4.html ...

> My program: **301** video frames; 440 audio frames
>
> ffprobe: **303** video frames; 440 audio frames

#2. production ID_3997798.mp4 from https://www.pexels.com/video/hands-hand-table-colorful-3997798/ ...

> My program: **736** video frames; no audio frames
>
> ffprobe: **738** video frames; no audio frames

I found more videos with this difference, but it ONLY happens in the video streams.

Is there something I am forgetting? There seem to be always 2 frames behind what ffprobe shows.

Thank you.

Comment: Check if the last frames of the input video file are marked as "discarded". See the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70578206/inconsistent-frame-number-with-ffmpeg) for details.

Comment: Hello.

I've used `ffmpeg -i <media file> -c copy -f null -` to compare ffmpeg with ffprobe, and the totals were the same.

Comment: I've also used `ffprobe -i <media file> -show_frames` and noticed that for both sample videos, there were TWO video frames at the end, with `pkt_dts=N/A` AND `pkt_dts=N/A`.

Not sure if this is a way to tell they are "discarded". But it seems that av_read_frame() / avcodec_receive_frame() are just simply ignoring them and there is no way of accessing them (why would I want to do that anyway).

But the point here is, why the ff tools are counting them by default, and libav not.

Comment: I meant `pkt_dts=N/A` AND `pkt_dts_time=N/A` in the comment above.

Comment: I meant executing `ffprobe input.mp4 -select_streams v:0 -show_packets`, and looking for `flags=_D`

Comment: @Rotem Oh, I see. OK. For both videos I got `flags=K_` right in the first packet. Other packets only have `flags=__`. I guess the "K" is for AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY. I just made the program to show `pkPacket->flags` and the first packet, -with a keyframe- IS NOT being ignored. Also, to get to the first frame, 3 calls to `avcodec_send_packet()` are required (the first one is the keyframe). The other frames only require one single call.
Does this say something to you?

Comment: I think the decoder has a buffer (FIFO) of 3 frames (this is normal, that you are not getting the decoded frame after the first call). I suppose there is a part missing from your code: After breaking the loop, and before `av_packet_free`, add `iError=avcodec_send_packet(ccCodecCtx, NULL);`, and `avcodec_receive_frame` if `iError==0`. Passing NULL packets flushes the decoder. Look how they pass `NULL` at [this example](https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/decode__video_8c_source.html): `/* flush the decoder */`  `decode(c, picture, NULL, outfilename);`

Comment: @Rotem After sending the "flush packet", I'm able to receive two more frames before getting an EOF. This solves the mystery (need more tests, though).

But I don't get this concept of getting another frame when I'm explicitly calling `av_read_frame()` until it's not possible anymore.

Also, according to the help on `av_read_frame()`, "If the decoder still has frames buffered, it will return them after sending a flush packet". Why would it have still buffered frames when I'm calling `avcodec_receive_frame()` (until it fails) to get everyone? And what packet do these extra frames belong to??

Comment: At the end of file, there are no more packets to read from the input file, but there are still buffered packets in the decoder. Writing NULLs is the way to decode the buffered packets. Why are there buffered packets? Due to B-Frafes and because there is no mark for end of frame and due to efficiency reasons.

Comment: @Rotem OK, I'll have to read more about that concept.
Question: are these extra (two in my samples) frames discardable? If not, where in the sequence of frames do they go? At the end?